# How do I make the XBox 360 slim recognise a USB backup?

Tags: xbox-360

I used to own an older model XBox 360 (the big white model). I took a USB backup of my saved games, etc. to an 8GB USB stick. I then needed to use this USB stick for something else, so I used `dd` on Linux to copy the entire drive's image to a file on my PC.

I eventually replaced the older XBox 360 with a newer XBox 360 Slim model. I took the exact same USB stick, used `dd` to put the image back on, and tried to recover my data from it. But the new XBox simply prompts me to configure it — it doesn't recognise the data on it at all.

I have to admit, it didn't even occur to me that a byte-for-byte image wouldn't work like this, so I don't really have any other backups. I've also tried letting the new XBox "configure" the USB stick and then (on Linux) replacing the files on it with the files from the mounted image I took, but again, I get prompted to reconfigure it.

How can I get the new XBox to recognise the USB drive formatted by the old model?